# How to stop IntelliJ from switching back to project code style?

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ (Community 2019.3.4) keeps switching the active code style from Default to Project. I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's triggered by branch switches and/or other Git operations. I'm doing those outside IntelliJ, not using its built-in Git interface.

So, why is IntelliJ constantly overriding the code style, and how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 3):

The Code Style settings are stored under `$projectRoot$/.idea/codeStyles`.

[image]

To use the standard `Project.xml` (*Project*) configuration, the `codeStyleConfig.xml` file should contain:

```
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />
  </state>
</component>
```

[image]

---

When at *IDE - Default*, `codeStyleConfig.xml` should contain:

```
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="Default" />
  </state>
</component>
```

Comment: That file isn't checked into Git, though. So why does it keep switching?

Comment: @Jorn if you have that file, it doesn't matter it isn't checked-in, it will always use Project.
When you set to Default again, you should see that file (codeStyleConfig.xml) changes.

Comment: I've been busy, so only had time to check just now. There's no `codeStyleConfig.xml` file in that folder, but there is a `codeStyles` file (no extension). It doesn't seem to change when I switch from Project to Default or back. Should I delete the file and see if that solves things?

Comment: Well, deleting that file has caused a codeStyles folder to appear with the xml file you mentioned. And switching the style from Project to Default (again...) did indeed change the file contents in the way you indicated. I'll let you know if it switches back again.

Comment: @Jorn ok! Let me know

Comment: Still happens. IntelliJ just decides to go back to the project config, and makes me set it back to default.